# biber doesn't work on M1 Mac?

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber, mac

I recently installed BasicTex on my M1 Mac (biber, biblatex, bibtex, all three are installed). I wanted to convert my tex file into PDF. There are citations which I have included in my tex. After running `pdflatex`, I get a PDF. Now, when I run `biber "filename"`, I get the following error:

> zsh: bad CPU type in executable: biber

How can I fix this error and run `biber`?

Comment: Exactly which arch did the installer choose? Universal darwin?

Comment: Apparently some people manage to run Biber on an M1 Mac (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/368), so maybe BasicTeX installs the wrong binaries (for the wrong platfrom)? Note that the Biber binaries are not built by the TeX live maintainers.

Comment: I have an MacBookPro laptop with the M1 Max chip, MacOS 12.1 Monterey, and "full" MacTeX2021. `biber` runs just fine on this system.

Comment: @Mico which arch did MacTeX install?

Comment: @user529295 - Sorry, what does "arch" mean?

Comment: Do you have Rosetta installed? If not, run a GUI application that is Intel only and you will get a dialog for installing Rosetta. I expect Bieber will then run.

Comment: @Mico arch - architecture. Apple uses arm64. You can find the arch by running 'file biber' at 'biber' installation directory. The installation directory could be found by running 'which biber' on terminal.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I didn't try with Rosetta installed. I will try it now.

Comment: @user529295 - I get the following response when I execute `file biber` per your suggestion: `biber: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`.

Comment: @Mico : do you have Rosetta installed?

Comment: @HerbSchulz - There are 7 files in the folder `/usr/libexec/rosetta`, and running `lsbom -f /Library/Apple/System/Library/Receipts/com.apple.pkg.RosettaUpdateAuto.bom` produces three "hits". According to [this posting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427996/19626), this means that Rosetta is indeed installed.

Comment: @Mico : and that is why Biber runs for you.

Comment: @HerbSchulz - Are there any downsides to getting Rosetta 2 installed on an M1-chip Mac? (I'm not aware of any...)

Comment: @Mico : the only negative is that some software authors will get too lazy to create universal or ARM versions of their software and eventually macOS will no longer support Rosetta so their software will stop working. Rosetta 1 & 2 are amazing pieces of work.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the [current default download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/MacOS/biber-darwin_universal.tar.gz/download) Universal binary from SourceForge which is for MacOS >10.12 and is universal x86_64/Arm64.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid Rosetta on my Mac Pro M1. To solve this problem, you can do this:

1. open the terminal and find out where `biber` and `biblatex` are installed:

   ```bash
   % type biber
   biber is /Library/TeX/texbin/biber
   ```

   ```bash
   % kpsewhich biblatex.sty
   /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
   ```
2. don't forget to make a backup before execute the next two steps ;-)
3. replace `biber` with https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/MacOS/biber-darwin_arm.tar.gz/download
4. replace the whole `biblatex` directory with (keep directory structure of the old one) https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/biblatex-3.17/

Comment: will there be a Universal version of biber for TL 2022?

Comment: Yes - I have just managed to generate a Universal binary for `biber` (x86_64+Arm64) which is now on Sourceforge if you want to try it. This is now the download default for OSX. The "legacy" binary is for OSX x86_64 10.6-10.12.